# Issue parsing Json data from GET

Tags: json, go

I have data coming from a webservice:

```
[  
   {  
      "meter_id":"3",
      "Values":[  
         {  
            "label":"SMAXSN",
            "value":"E190912121751 01980"
         },
         {  
            "label":"MSG1",
            "value":" PAS DE MESSAGE"
         },
         {  
            "label":"PCOUP",
            "value":"03"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF10",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"STGE",
            "value":"003A0001"
         },
         {  
            "label":"URMS1",
            "value":"235"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF06",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EAST",
            "value":"004191456"
         },
         {  
            "label":"PREF",
            "value":"03"
         },
         {  
            "label":"SMAXSN-1",
            "value":"E190911223945 01940"
         },
         {  
            "label":"DATE",
            "value":"E190912152027"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASD02",
            "value":"000610281"
         },
         {  
            "label":"PJOURF+1",
            "value":"00008001 NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE"
         },
         {  
            "label":"NJOURF+1",
            "value":"00"
         },
         {  
            "label":"ADSC",
            "value":"021775806277"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASD03",
            "value":"000045963"
         },
         {  
            "label":"LTARF",
            "value":" BASE"
         },
         {  
            "label":"CCASN-1",
            "value":"E190912143000 00144"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF01",
            "value":"004191456"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASD04",
            "value":"000134889"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASD01",
            "value":"003400323"
         },
         {  
            "label":"SINSTS",
            "value":"00326"
         },
         {  
            "label":"CCASN",
            "value":"E190912150000 00156"
         },
         {  
            "label":"VTIC",
            "value":"02"
         },
         {  
            "label":"IRMS1",
            "value":"001"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF03",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF04",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF08",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"RELAIS",
            "value":"000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF02",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"NJOURF",
            "value":"00"
         },
         {  
            "label":"NTARF",
            "value":"01"
         },
         {  
            "label":"UMOY1",
            "value":"E190912152000 236"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF05",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"PRM",
            "value":"23545007228637"
         },
         {  
            "label":"timestamp",
            "value":"2019-09-12T15:20:02+02:00"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF09",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF07",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"NGTF",
            "value":" BASE"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "meter_id":"5",
      "Values":[  
         {  
            "label":"VTIC",
            "value":"02"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASD04",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EAST",
            "value":"003048661"
         },
         {  
            "label":"NTARF",
            "value":"01"
         },
         {  
            "label":"CCASN-1",
            "value":"E190912143000 00060"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF05",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF10",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"IRMS1",
            "value":"000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASD03",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"ADSC",
            "value":"021775056027"
         },
         {  
            "label":"CCASN",
            "value":"E190912150000 00058"
         },
         {  
            "label":"URMS1",
            "value":"241"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF07",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"DATE",
            "value":"E190912152021"
         },
         {  
            "label":"MSG1",
            "value":" PAS DE MESSAGE"
         },
         {  
            "label":"PJOURF+1",
            "value":"00008001 NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE"
         },
         {  
            "label":"PRM",
            "value":"23544717793089"
         },
         {  
            "label":"LTARF",
            "value":" BASE"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF06",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"NJOURF",
            "value":"00"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF04",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASD02",
            "value":"000329795"
         },
         {  
            "label":"timestamp",
            "value":"2019-09-12T15:20:09+02:00"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF08",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF09",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"SMAXSN-1",
            "value":"E190911071004 01100"
         },
         {  
            "label":"NGTF",
            "value":" BASE"
         },
         {  
            "label":"SMAXSN",
            "value":"E190912071628 01110"
         },
         {  
            "label":"PREF",
            "value":"06"
         },
         {  
            "label":"NJOURF+1",
            "value":"00"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASD01",
            "value":"002718866"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF03",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"STGE",
            "value":"003A4001"
         },
         {  
            "label":"RELAIS",
            "value":"000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF02",
            "value":"000000000"
         },
         {  
            "label":"SINSTS",
            "value":"00076"
         },
         {  
            "label":"UMOY1",
            "value":"E190912152000 240"
         },
         {  
            "label":"PCOUP",
            "value":"06"
         },
         {  
            "label":"EASF01",
            "value":"003048661"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

When parsed, I should get an array of `meters` with 2 items.

Here are my structs:

```
type Meter struct {
    MeterID string `json:"meter_id"`
    Values  []Line `json:"Values"`
}

type Line struct {
    Label string `json:"label"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}
```

When I display raw JSON with:

```
var data []map[string]interface{}
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
logger.SLog.Debug(data)
```

I can see I see several `meter` items

but when I try to parse it with:

```
var meters []Meter
err = json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&meters)
```

I also tried to parse data with:

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &meters)
if err != nil {
    logger.SLog.Debug(err)
}
logger.SLog.Debug(meters)
```

But same result, I only get 1 item in `meters`.

Why ?

Comment: Did you get anything from `err`?

Comment: I just checked it, and err is nil

Comment: I aslo tried to replace `var meters []Meter` by `meters := make([]Meter, 20)` but it didnt work

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro You have to show us the code that can be used to reproduce the error, otherwise there's no way for us to tell where the bug is. The code that you've provided works fine. https://play.golang.org/p/RPni_lCRJe4

Comment: updated my question,  `Decode` or `json.Unmarshal` is giving the same result, just one item. But when I print it with `[]map[string]interface{}` , I get all items. I can assume this is not a parsing issue, but maybe linked to HTTP GET.

Answer (score 0):

something is strange. I have tryed this code on Go Playground and it is ok, returns 2 items, look:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

type Meter struct {
    MeterID string `json:"meter_id"`
    Values  []Line `json:"Values"`
}

type Line struct {
    Label string `json:"label"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}


func main() {
    jsonData := `[{"meter_id":"3","Values":[{"label":"SMAXSN","value":"E190912121751 01980"},{"label":"MSG1","value":" PAS DE MESSAGE"},{"label":"PCOUP","value":"03"},{"label":"EASF10","value":"000000000"},{"label":"STGE","value":"003A0001"},{"label":"URMS1","value":"235"},{"label":"EASF06","value":"000000000"},{"label":"EAST","value":"004191456"},{"label":"PREF","value":"03"},{"label":"SMAXSN-1","value":"E190911223945 01940"},{"label":"DATE","value":"E190912152027"},{"label":"EASD02","value":"000610281"},{"label":"PJOURF+1","value":"00008001 NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE"},{"label":"NJOURF+1","value":"00"},{"label":"ADSC","value":"021775806277"},{"label":"EASD03","value":"000045963"},{"label":"LTARF","value":" BASE"},{"label":"CCASN-1","value":"E190912143000 00144"},{"label":"EASF01","value":"004191456"},{"label":"EASD04","value":"000134889"},{"label":"EASD01","value":"003400323"},{"label":"SINSTS","value":"00326"},{"label":"CCASN","value":"E190912150000 00156"},{"label":"VTIC","value":"02"},{"label":"IRMS1","value":"001"},{"label":"EASF03","value":"000000000"},{"label":"EASF04","value":"000000000"},{"label":"EASF08","value":"000000000"},{"label":"RELAIS","value":"000"},{"label":"EASF02","value":"000000000"},{"label":"NJOURF","value":"00"},{"label":"NTARF","value":"01"},{"label":"UMOY1","value":"E190912152000 236"},{"label":"EASF05","value":"000000000"},{"label":"PRM","value":"23545007228637"},{"label":"timestamp","value":"2019-09-12T15:20:02+02:00"},{"label":"EASF09","value":"000000000"},{"label":"EASF07","value":"000000000"},{"label":"NGTF","value":" BASE"}]},{"meter_id":"5","Values":[{"label":"VTIC","value":"02"},{"label":"EASD04","value":"000000000"},{"label":"EAST","value":"003048661"},{"label":"NTARF","value":"01"},{"label":"CCASN-1","value":"E190912143000 00060"},{"label":"EASF05","value":"000000000"},{"label":"EASF10","value":"000000000"},{"label":"IRMS1","value":"000"},{"label":"EASD03","value":"000000000"},{"label":"ADSC","value":"021775056027"},{"label":"CCASN","value":"E190912150000 00058"},{"label":"URMS1","value":"241"},{"label":"EASF07","value":"000000000"},{"label":"DATE","value":"E190912152021"},{"label":"MSG1","value":" PAS DE MESSAGE"},{"label":"PJOURF+1","value":"00008001 NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE"},{"label":"PRM","value":"23544717793089"},{"label":"LTARF","value":" BASE"},{"label":"EASF06","value":"000000000"},{"label":"NJOURF","value":"00"},{"label":"EASF04","value":"000000000"},{"label":"EASD02","value":"000329795"},{"label":"timestamp","value":"2019-09-12T15:20:09+02:00"},{"label":"EASF08","value":"000000000"},{"label":"EASF09","value":"000000000"},{"label":"SMAXSN-1","value":"E190911071004 01100"},{"label":"NGTF","value":" BASE"},{"label":"SMAXSN","value":"E190912071628 01110"},{"label":"PREF","value":"06"},{"label":"NJOURF+1","value":"00"},{"label":"EASD01","value":"002718866"},{"label":"EASF03","value":"000000000"},{"label":"STGE","value":"003A4001"},{"label":"RELAIS","value":"000"},{"label":"EASF02","value":"000000000"},{"label":"SINSTS","value":"00076"},{"label":"UMOY1","value":"E190912152000 240"},{"label":"PCOUP","value":"06"},{"label":"EASF01","value":"003048661"}]}]`
    //fmt.Printf("json: %s", jsonData)

    var meters []Meter
    err := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonData)).Decode(&meters)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
            return
    }

    jsonOut, err := json.Marshal(meters)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
    fmt.Printf("obj len: %d\n", len(meters))
    fmt.Printf("jsonOut: %s\n", jsonOut)
}
```

outputs:

```
obj len: 2
jsonOut: [{"meter_id":"3","Values":[{"label":"SMAXSN","value":"E190912121751 01980"},{"label":"MSG1","value":" PAS DE MESSAGE"},{"label":"PCOUP","value":"03"},{"label":"EASF10","value":"000000000"},{"label":"STGE","value":"003A0001"},{"label":"URMS1","value":"235"},{"label":"EASF06","value":"000000000"},{"label":"EAST","value":"004191456"},{"label":"PREF","value":"03"},{"label":"SMAXSN-1","value":"E190911223945 01940"},{"label":"DATE","value":"E190912152027"},{"label":"EASD02","value":"000610281"},{"label":"PJOURF+1","value":"00008001 NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE"},{"label":"NJOURF+1","value":"00"},{"label":"ADSC","value":"021775806277"},{"label":"EASD03","value":"000045963"},{"label":"LTARF","value":" BASE"},{"label":"CCASN-1","value":"E190912143000 00144"},{"label":"EASF01","value":"004191456"},{"label":"EASD04","value":"000134889"},{"label":"EASD01","value":"003400323"},{"label":"SINSTS","value":"00326"},{"label":"CCASN","value":"E190912150000 00156"},{"label":"VTIC","value":"02"},{"label":"IRMS1","value":"001"},{"label":"EASF03","value":"000000000"},{"label":"EASF04","value":"000000000"},{"label":"EASF08","value":"000000000"},{"label":"RELAIS","value":"000"},{"label":"EASF02","value":"000000000"},{"label":"NJOURF","value":"00"},{"label":"NTARF","value":"01"},{"label":"UMOY1","value":"E190912152000 236"},{"label":"EASF05","value":"000000000"},{"label":"PRM","value":"23545007228637"},{"label":"timestamp","value":"2019-09-12T15:20:02+02:00"},{"label":"EASF09","value":"000000000"},{"label":"EASF07","value":"000000000"},{"label":"NGTF","value":" BASE"}]},{"meter_id":"5","Values":[{"label":"VTIC","value":"02"},{"label":"EASD04","value":"000000000"},{"label":"EAST","value":"003048661"},{"label":"NTARF","value":"01"},{"label":"CCASN-1","value":"E190912143000 00060"},{"label":"EASF05","value":"000000000"},{"label":"EASF10","value":"000000000"},{"label":"IRMS1","value":"000"},{"label":"EASD03","value":"000000000"},{"label":"ADSC","value":"021775056027"},{"label":"CCASN","value":"E190912150000 00058"},{"label":"URMS1","value":"241"},{"label":"EASF07","value":"000000000"},{"label":"DATE","value":"E190912152021"},{"label":"MSG1","value":" PAS DE MESSAGE"},{"label":"PJOURF+1","value":"00008001 NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE NONUTILE"},{"label":"PRM","value":"23544717793089"},{"label":"LTARF","value":" BASE"},{"label":"EASF06","value":"000000000"},{"label":"NJOURF","value":"00"},{"label":"EASF04","value":"000000000"},{"label":"EASD02","value":"000329795"},{"label":"timestamp","value":"2019-09-12T15:20:09+02:00"},{"label":"EASF08","value":"000000000"},{"label":"EASF09","value":"000000000"},{"label":"SMAXSN-1","value":"E190911071004 01100"},{"label":"NGTF","value":" BASE"},{"label":"SMAXSN","value":"E190912071628 01110"},{"label":"PREF","value":"06"},{"label":"NJOURF+1","value":"00"},{"label":"EASD01","value":"002718866"},{"label":"EASF03","value":"000000000"},{"label":"STGE","value":"003A4001"},{"label":"RELAIS","value":"000"},{"label":"EASF02","value":"000000000"},{"label":"SINSTS","value":"00076"},{"label":"UMOY1","value":"E190912152000 240"},{"label":"PCOUP","value":"06"},{"label":"EASF01","value":"003048661"}]}]
```

Test link: https://play.golang.org/p/8hFz43YQ2RP

Comment: yep, so problem remains but is else where

Comment: I posted it for you to analyze as I could not reproduce the error. You can try piecemeal until you find what's wrong with your code, also debugging can help.

Comment: You len(meters) returns only 1? The json input matches with 2 items on debug?

Comment: Yes, it seems that issue is not in parsing, but in the GET request... I understand it is difficult to help when you can't reproduce error